# Sort information from a webpage

Tags: java, sorting

I have a webpage which has 10 separate text input spaces.  I need to sort (alphabetize) the text from those input spaces (based on the first word from each input).  For example, if the boxes were:

cat

---

dog

---

apple

They would need to be:
apple

---

cat

---

dog

I need to do this on the fly.  What are some options for doing this?  I have experience in both Java and Python if that helps.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you need that on the fly in a webpage, you should look at Javascript, not Java.

Comment: Indeed, on the fly would imply javascript, checkout: http://www.wrichards.com/blog/2009/02/jquery-sorting-elements/
either that, or some ajax-call to a server component which sorts, but that seems like overkill to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put these items into a `List<String>`, then you can call `Collections.sort()` on your list. That list instance will then be sorted into the natural order based on the `String` class.